# How to reuse a scenario in citrus framework?

Tags: continuous-integration, refactoring, integration-testing, code-reuse, citrus-framework

I set this testing scenario with citrus framework. Now I'm trying to reuse it in other scenarios.
I'm creating a behavior for each step. My behaviors are mainly http requests

```
public class NoProductDocumentValidationScenarioIT {

    private @CitrusResource TestContext parentContext;

    @CitrusEndpoint(name = "todoBasicAuthClient")
    private HttpClient cmsAuthClient;

    @CitrusEndpoint(name = "vdmBasicAuthClient")
    private HttpClient vdmAuthClient;

    @CitrusEndpoint(name = "gvHttpClient")
    private HttpClient gvHttpClient;

    @Test
    @CitrusTest
    public String NoProductDocumentValidation(@CitrusResource TestRunner runner, @CitrusResource TestContext context)
            throws BadNewsMLG2Exception {
        String pdtIdentifier = "EDIT-FR-SVID2-YM9N001479";
        String videoDocument = VideoDocument.setUpVideoDocument("fr", "v1_afptv_sport_broadcast_photos");
        int jobPublicationID = 5;
        // CMS Authentification
        TestBehavior authenticateCMS = new ProductAuthenticationBehavior(cmsAuthClient);
        ApplyTestBehaviorAction authenticateActionCMS = new ApplyTestBehaviorAction(runner, authenticateCMS);
        authenticateActionCMS.doExecute(context);

        // Document Creation
        CreateVideoDocumentBehavior createDoc = new CreateVideoDocumentBehavior(cmsAuthClient, pdtIdentifier,
                videoDocument);
        ApplyTestBehaviorAction createDocAction = new ApplyTestBehaviorAction(runner, createDoc);
        createDocAction.doExecute(context);

        // get document data
        videoDocument = createDoc.getVideoDocument();
        G2VideoDocument g2VideoDocument = ((G2VideoDocument) G2ObjectFactory.parse(videoDocument));
        g2VideoDocument.getProducts();
        String linkToVideoDocument = g2VideoDocument.getLinkToSelf().toString();
        String linkToProject = g2VideoDocument.getLinkToVideoProject().toString();
        String projectID = IrisStringTools.extractIdFromUri(linkToProject);
        String documentID = IrisStringTools.extractIdFromUri(linkToVideoDocument);
        String etag = g2VideoDocument.getEditorialTag();

        // Lock document Metadata
        EditVideoDocumentMetaBehavior lockDocMeta = new EditVideoDocumentMetaBehavior(cmsAuthClient, pdtIdentifier,
                videoDocument, documentID);
        ApplyTestBehaviorAction lockDocMetaAction = new ApplyTestBehaviorAction(runner, lockDocMeta);
        lockDocMetaAction.doExecute(context);
}
}
```

I run this in eclipse as JUnit test.

I thought about using a super class but it didn't work.

```
public class ProductDocumentValidationScenarioIT extends NoProductDocumentValidationScenarioIT {

    public String ProductDocumentValidation(@CitrusResource TestRunner runner, @CitrusResource TestContext context)
            throws BadNewsMLG2Exception {
                return something;

    }
}
```

Comment: Test behaviors is the way to go here. What issues do you have with using test behaviors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what we finally did is to create a behavior runner (a java class) where all the behaviors are instanciated and then in the scenario we call the behavior runner with the behavior constant corresponding to the behavior I need:

```
public class BehaviorRunner {
private void doExecute(TestRunner runner, TestContext context, TestBehavior testBehavior) {
    ApplyTestBehaviorAction behaviorAction = new ApplyTestBehaviorAction(runner,testBehavior);
    behaviorAction.doExecute(context);
}

public void execute( String behaviorLabel, @CitrusResource TestRunner runner, @CitrusResource TestContext context) {
    try {
        switch (behaviorLabel) {
            case BehaviorConstants.CREATE_VIDEO_DOCUMENT :
                CreateVideoDocumentBehavior createVideoDocumentBehavior = new CreateVideoDocumentBehavior(cmsAuthClient, pdtIdentifier, VideoDocument.setUpVideoDocument2(LanguageConstants.EN, "v1_afptv_sport_broadcast_photos"));
                doExecute(runner, context, createVideoDocumentBehavior);
                break;
            case BehaviorConstants.MOVIEDRAFT :
                MovieDraftDocumentBehavior movieDraftDocumentBehavior = new MovieDraftDocumentBehavior(cmsAuthClient, pdtIdentifier, 1, g2VideoDoc);
                doExecute(runner, context, movieDraftDocumentBehavior);     
                break;
            case BehaviorConstants.PUBLICATION_PROGRESSION_STATUS:
                GetPublicationProgressionStatusBehavior publicationProgressionStatusBehavior = new GetPublicationProgressionStatusBehavior(vdmAuthClient, pdtIdentifier , g2VideoDoc);
                doExecute(runner, context, publicationProgressionStatusBehavior);   
                break;
            case BehaviorConstants.VALIDATE :
                ValidateDocumentBehavior validateDocumentBehavior = new ValidateDocumentBehavior(cmsAuthClient, pdtIdentifier, g2VideoDoc);
                doExecute(runner, context, validateDocumentBehavior);   
                break;
            default:
                    break;
        }
```

we ended up with a scenario like this:

```
@Test
@CitrusTest
public void NoProductDocumentValidation(@CitrusResource TestRunner runner, @CitrusResource TestContext context) throws BadNewsMLG2Exception {
    slf4jLogger.info("Montage analysis scenario START");
    // execute scenario
    // Document Creation 
    behaviorRunner.execute(BehaviorConstants.CREATE_VIDEO_DOCUMENT, runner, context);
    // Lock document Metadata
    behaviorRunner.execute(BehaviorConstants.EDITOR, runner, context);
    // Lock Document Binary 
    behaviorRunner.execute(BehaviorConstants.BINARY_EDITOR, runner, context);
```

That saved us a lot of code lines since we're using different combinations of behaviors in different scenarios.

I hope this would help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Test behaviors is the way to go here. I suggest to use something like this

```
CreateVideoDocumentBehavior createDoc = new CreateVideoDocumentBehavior(cmsAuthClient, pdtIdentifier,
                videoDocument);

runner.applyBehavior(createDoc);
```

Comment: what's the difference between :
`runner.applyBehavior(createDoc);`
and:


`ApplyTestBehaviorAction createDocAction = new ApplyTestBehaviorAction(runner, createDoc);
        createDocAction.doExecute(context);`